# detecting in-use @font-face via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to sniff the formatting for a `<p>` so I can pass the info to an `<iframe>` and match formats.

I can get the font face using jQuery

```
var font = $("p").css('font-family');
var fsiz = $("p").css('font-size');
```

However if the font-family is a web font - eg "Open Sans" I also need to find the src for the `@font-face` rule that loaded it.

I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: What do you need to "find the src" for?

Comment: I need to recreate the @font-face inside the iframe to make the text inside match the text on the parent page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find all css-defined fonts, demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vCmtk/1/) (console).

```
function getFonts (obj) {
    var o = obj || {},
        sheet = document.styleSheets,
        rule = null,
        i = sheet.length, j;
    while( 0 <= --i ){
        rule = sheet[i].rules || sheet[i].cssRules || [];
        j = rule.length;
        while( 0 <= --j ){
            if( rule[j].constructor.name === 'CSSFontFaceRule' ){ // rule[j].slice(0, 10).toLowerCase() === '@font-face'
                o[ rule[j].style.fontFamily ] = rule[j].style.src;
            };
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: [According to @Roemer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5725165), this does not work in FF

Comment: @KyleMit , In _FireFox_, you can find font rules with `rule[j] instanceof CSSFontFaceRule`, but then extracting the actual data from it doesn't seem neat, looks like you have to parse it out of the rule text

Comment: This fiddle outputs: {foo: "url("bar.otf")"} for me.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the chosen solution to work as well in IE and FF, also Safari on iOs. The chosen solution only worked in Chrome. (Alas I cannot - yet - add comments to that solution, that's why I put it in a seperate solution.)

```
function getFonts (obj) {
    var o = obj || {},
        sheets = document.styleSheets,
        rules = null,
        i = sheets.length, j;
    while( 0 <= --i ){
        rules =  sheets[i].cssRules || sheets[i].rules || []; // I swapped those two, IE would go wrong
        j = rules.length;
        while( 0 <= --j ){
            if( rules[j].toString() == "[object CSSFontFaceRule]" ){  // This works in IE and FF too
                o[ rules[j].style.fontFamily ] = rules[j].style.src;
            };
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: There is an error in your code. You are making use of undeclared variable 'rule'.

Comment: I fixed it, but Chrome the latest Chrome throws a DOM exception. You can't access these rules anymore, it seems. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the rules/rule error. the DOM exception is over my head and no time to do research at the moment.

Comment: Chrome simply won't let you access these properties anymore. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks for noting; I had to adapt some important code for my company because of this.

Comment: If anyone finds a solution/workaround -- I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

As a small improvement on [Paul S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13171633/148824)'s answer, I've included nested objects with the font weight and style as keys, to retrieve all versions of a font.

```
function getFonts (obj) {
    var o = obj || {},
        sheet = document.styleSheets,
        rule = null,
        i = sheet.length, j;
    while( 0 <= --i ){
        rule = sheet[i].rules || sheet[i].cssRules || [];
        j = rule.length;
        while( 0 <= --j ){
            if( rule[j].constructor.name === 'CSSFontFaceRule' ){
                if (!(rule[j].style.fontFamily in o)) o[ rule[j].style.fontFamily ] = Object.create(null);
                o[ rule[j].style.fontFamily ][ rule[j].style.fontWeight + '-' + rule[j].style.fontStyle ] = rule[j].style.src;
            };
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```